# Map{box,libre} expression syntax for dynamic property value

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I am stuck trying to write an expression that evaluates to a number for my paint.circle-radius property.

If I set something like this, to use the `radius` feature property, it works fine:

```js
"circle-radius": {
  property: "radius",
  type: "exponential",
  stops: [
    [{ zoom: 9, value: 1 }, 10],
    [{ zoom: 9, value: 10 }, 80]
  ]
},
```

Trying to use an expression to calculate the value does not work:

```js
"circle-radius": [
  "literal",
  {
    property: ["case", ["has", "other"], "other", "radius"],
    type: "exponential",
    stops: [
      [{ zoom: 9, value: 1 }, 10],
      [{ zoom: 9, value: 10 }, 80]
    ]
  }
]
```

The full example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mclean-zftnpr?file=/index.html

I would expect a yellow circle on the top with a radius of 10. Instead, the layer does not render, and all you see are the tomato circles.

Error in console:

> circle-radius: Expected number but found object instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using property syntax that was deprecated years ago, and attempting to combine it with current expression syntax in a way that won't work.

You want something like this:

```
"circle-radius": 
  ["interpolate", 
      ["case", ["has", "other"], ["get", "other"], ["get", "radius"]],
      1, 10, 
      10, 80
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. I have additional requirements, such as interpolating based on zoom level. I can open a different question as you answered my original one. The additional requirement in case people are interested, now:
how do account for zoom:
["zoom"]